# On Form submit, execute some PHP and then Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

This is what I am trying to do:
When a form is submitted (by clicking a button)

1. I want to insert some data to MySQL data using PHP
2. Based on the success on the insert, I want to run some JavaScript(JS) code. (In reality some more data will be inserted from a JS array using AJAX but in the test code below, I am simply showing alert with the array). Also, I need the PHP to execute first because I need to the autoincremetn ID from MySQL via PHP, using the `mysqli_insert_id()` function.
3. After all the data has been inserted (or both PHP and JS code has executed), I want to return to the same page which initiated the submit, in the test code this page is called `test.php`.

Below is my test code (in `test.php` page):

```
<?php

// Require the configuration which controls controls error reporting:
require ('config.inc.php');

// Require the database connection:
require (MYSQL);

/* PAGE CONTENT STARTS HERE! */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--JQUERY-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var store_categories = []; 
    function init_filtering() {
        store_categories.push('data1');
        alert ("alert1: "+ store_categories);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">$( init_filtering );</script>

</head>  
<body>

<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      $q = "INSERT INTO sms_category (sms_updated_id, category) VALUES (1, 'categories')";      
      $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    }

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert ("alert2: "+ store_categories);
    </script>
<?php
} // end if
?>

<form id="edit_data" action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What is happening right now:

1. Alert1 is properly showing the data in the `store_categories` array
2. But when I click the submit button, Alert2 is still showing blank (or, only "alert2:", i.e. cant show the value in the `store_categories` array).

So, this is my question:

1. Why is alert2 not showing the `store_categories` array?
2. What can I do so that `store_categories` array has its value when I click submit button?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're confusing client-side with server-side. PHP code is executed on the server while JS is executed on the client.

Comment: what does alert2 show. Does is shows "alert2:" or shows nothing

Comment: Hi Polin: yes, it shows "alert2:". (I have edited my original post).

Comment: alfasin: thanks for your comments; I am aware of the differences. I have explained below why I am using both PHP and JS array. Do let me know if you think there is a better way to achieve the same objective.

Comment: A) you don't state *what* you want to achieve but rather *how* you're trying to do it - so it's pretty difficult to answer, and B) If you want to submit a form to the same page - perform an insert and stay on the same page - you can do it with simple HTML & PHP - no need to JS/AJAX. If you're having a problem of running in endless loop after submit - then you'll have to check the passed parameters and add a "stop" parameter that will prevent the page from keep submitting itself.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve: My page is basically a form - with multiple input fields. The page/form also has a JQery UI 'drag and drop' feature which acts as an 'intuitive' way for the user to select his choices/options. On form submit, all values must be saved - those in the input fields as well as those chosen by the user via the 'drag and drop'. Hope this explains what I am trying to achieve. Do let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

May be It works Try it.
I think when form is submitted then only second alert will displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">init_filtering()</script>
    <?php
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
          $q = "INSERT INTO sms_category (sms_updated_id, category) VALUES (1, 'categories')";      
          $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
   ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert ("alert2: "+ store_categories);
        </script>
    <?php
    } 
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Hi, you are right that when the form is submitted only second alert is shown. But the array `store_categories` does not have any value, which is the main problem here.

Comment: there is no problem. I think there is problem with calling the function with $(init_filtering), Try to call as normal

Comment: I called the function as normal (`init_filtering();`) and yes the alert2 shows the array. But I need the function to run after document has loaded (i.e. with `$( init_filtering );`) as in the real code the `init_filtering` function will also access some `DOM` elements such as `div`s. By the way, one strange thing I noticed when I ran the function using `init_filtering();` is that when I click submit, alert1 appears for a second time first and then alert2. Previously (when using (`$( init_filtering );`), after submit button was clicked alert2 appeared first (but without array) and then alert1.

Comment: put init_filtering() in $(document).ready(). for call function after the document loaded.

Comment: Hi Krishna, I have done as suggested by using `$(document).ready(init_filtering);` instead of `$( init_filtering );` but there is no change, i.e. alert2 still cannot show the array.

Comment: use this code $(document).ready(function(){ init_filtering() });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19016/discussion-between-krishna-and-shahriar-n-khondokar)

Comment: Hi Krishna...sorry I was away...however, the code you have provided doesn't seem to make any difference.